# How to save and load HTML image in WebView?

Tags: java, android, image, webview

I make an email application. When user views html, it will load the HTML images at first, when user views it next time, it will load the HTML images from internet again. It can not save bandwith.
Can I save the image? If it is possible, can I load it in WebView?

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your HTML content in order to download images and put it on the device sdcard.
You can then replace all images src in the HTML by your file absolute path on disk.

```
String htmlToParse = item.getContent();

                Elements tags = Jsoup.parse(htmlToParse).select("img");
                if (!tags.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Element tag : tags) {
                        String url = tag.attr("src");
                        File f = downloadImage(url);
                        htmlToParse.replace(url, f.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks it is not easy to coding.

Comment: In order to parse the HTML content, you can use jsoup library. See the code in my response

Comment: Thank you very much, let me try.

Comment: Thanks for your hlep, it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

you can load it by using

web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHtmlData(this,"IMAGEPATH");

Answer (score 0):

I will override onLoadResource (be careful as not only images but all sort of resources, like CSS) manually download the image and store it locally.

---

- another solution

  1. Download the all HTML content
  2. Parse the content to get the images URLs
  3. Download the images and store them locally
  4. Replace URLs with your local path: `src="file:///android_asset/html/image2.jpg"`